# GoogleAutocompleteViewController: Cancel method from delegate does not working

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I'm using the google's autocomplete places picker, but the following method does not being triggered:

```js
//extension ServicesViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
  viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)  
}
```

What could be happening?

Best Regards

Comment: did you conform `GMSAutocompleteViewController`'s `delegate`?

Comment: Yep, I've already done this. The only method that's not trigger is cancel button action.

Comment: could you please share more about your code? Maybe we'll get more with more code.

Comment: Hi @emrcftci that's my code: https://gist.github.com/alfredolucomav/2f3e57676c10e818090db3259d0c6b76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should conform the `delegate` of the `GMSAutocompleteViewController`.

```swift
let controller = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
controller.delegate = self // <-- Set the delegate
present(controller, animated: true)
```

Then you should call delegate methods

```swift
// MARK: - GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate

extension ServicesViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

  public func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true)  
  }
}
```